# Can I make an element droppable just for one element with simple HTML and Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, draggable, droppable

So it is possible to make an element droppable just for one element with simple HTML and Javascript

Comment: Could you add some more detail about what you have tried already, or the specifications that you are thinking of in this case? Theres allot of grey area in this question - please be more specific

Comment: I guess this answers your question https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_draganddrop.asp?

Comment: More specific ? I just don't want two elements to be able to be dropped on one element so if i drag one element to the dropped element I don't want dropped element to be droppable anymore